# How to install the Windows 7 look on Zorin OS, Ubuntu Based Distro

Tags: zorin

The default interface of Zorin OS is a Windows 7 like interface, which is what I am looking for:

[image: Zorin OS Win7 Interface]

In the [gallery page](http://zorin-os.com/gallery.html) of the Zorin OS website, it shows, the option to change to a Windows 7, XP, 2000 interface.

I downloaded the **free** [Zorin OS Lite](http://zorin-os.com/free.html), installed it next to Windows 7(dual boot). After I installed it, the interface was a Windows 2000 like interface. I found out in the Zorin OS look changer, that I only have the option of changing the looks to Windows 2000 Or Mac OS X. Don't like either of them.

This is for a former Windows user, he has an old PC, with Win7, thats just too slow. and I want to make his transition to Linux* as enjoyable as possible. Hence the Windows 7 look is needed.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet myself, but I'm pretty sure that the problem was choosing the Lite version. If you download the free Core package, I think you'll get the UI similar to Win7.

Answer (score 2):

When you're main objective is to get a Linux-based Windows-lookalike and you're not stuck with Zorin (of which I've never heard before<sup>1</sup>), I'd recommend **Linux Mint + KDE + Windows 7 themes**. Themes I've found there are much closer to the Windows (7 or 8) look than what I could see from your Zorin reference AND extremely easy to install, IMHO.

There is a risk, though, since using KDE requires a certain level of graphics hardware performance. On the other hand, I'm using a 7 years old 2x2.26GHz@3GB RAM laptop with Intel Integrated Graphics 4500MHD and it runs great (Linux Mint 17.1).

Example of the themes provided by the Linux Mint community:

[image][image]

However, I agree with the statement that sometimes change can be for the better. It gives you the chance to start fresh and get to know the advantages of the new that you might miss when trying to stick with the old forever. Having said that, the default Linux Mint Cinnamon<sup>2</sup> desktop is worth a try. ;)

---

<sup>1</sup> You might also want to take into consideration that while ZorinOS is certainly an interesting project that is worth being tested (for yourself), it's probably not the best idea to choose for a distribution with such a small community (support). The bigger the community the likelier it is that you will be able to help your friend when problems occure.

<sup>2</sup> which is also highly customizable

Comment: Best I think is Xfce (in Ubuntu or Mint). It's lightweight, very customizable and pretty much alike to KDE (in terms and GUI settings) - actually I think Xfce now is a Gtk+ clone of KDE. I don't own any Windows 7, so can't tell all similarities but for sure the ain't no dock-alike panel in Xfce like in Windows 7's taskbar, but of course you can use docky instead of xfce4-panel. BTW, Cinnamon consumes a lot of CPU too (50~60% of my Pentium M) and need GPU in order to work.

Comment: Noted. But, this is a dualboot, if he thinks he can work with Zorin, and it's faster than Windows, then I may have successfully converted someone to Linux. And maybe later I can switch him to Ubuntu Trusty Thar. For now, I asked, he is fine with this interface. So, time will tell if he actually likes it... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @blade19899 Sorry, that I couldn't answer your quesiton, your profiles reveals that you're actually very much knowing what your doing so good luck with it ;) groetjes.